# ¿Como podría introducir una empresa en la siguiente jerarquía de clases?

Tags: java

Buenos días, mi duda consiste en cómo puedo introducir a una clase Empresa, dentro de la siguiente jerarquía de clases. 
[image: Jerarquía de clases Clientes]

Entiendo que un Cliente es una Persona o es una Empresa (Persona Juridica), pero claro la clase Cliente ya no podría extender dos clases.

Si las declaro como interfaces, ya no me sería muy util la herencia para que los empleados del taller heredasen los campos y métodos en común.

Comment: sin saber muy bien como funcionaria cada clase, para dicidir sobre composicion, quizas es esposible que Empresa encaje bien heredando de Cliente.Saludos

Comment: Eso pensé aunque por la relacion es-un no me cuadraba. Quizás en etapas prematuras del código debería distinguirlo por campos, y despues refactorizar si la cosa va 'in crechendo'. Thanks por tu comentario.

Answer (score 0):

Si la herencia no se sabe utilizar puede ser caotica principalmente porque terminarías en una jerarquía que olvides quien es el tipo base o hasta desestabilizar todo el diseño de tus clases agregandole métodos y clases a los principales tipos bases que siquiera utilizaran(siendo este solo uno de los casos mas comunes).

Por eso te recomendaría [composición sobre herencia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)(perdona que esta en inglés. Es la mejor deficion que puedo encontrar). Lo considero mejor porque principalmente guía al siguiente desarrollador sobre el diseño de tus clases y hasta a ti mismo.

No digo que la herencia sea mala. Solo digo que si no se sabe cómo utilizar, puede ser la peor pesadilla.

Aquí otro link en [devexperto.com](https://devexperto.com/herencia-vs-composicion/)

Comment: La tería más o menos la tengo conceptualizada, otra cosa es saber plasmarla XD, de ahí mi duda. Aún así, gracias por el comentario y revisaré los links que pusiste.